# how to reduce the space in a equation in latex?

Tags: spacing, equations

general, the equation in latex looks like:

[image: general]

But in some paper, the equation looks more compact, like

[image: compact]

There is less space among the equation. How to make such a configuration?

Comment: Welcome! Well, the fonts are different for one thing and various font dimensions are used to determine the spacing. Also, there are differences between, for example, inline maths and display maths environments in terms of layout and spacing. And, of course, we don't know the second is produced by TeX. It certainly looks rather squashed, don't you think?

Comment: I am sure it is created by latex. and they are both display equation. but I have no idea about the font.

Comment: Mathtools provide a cramped style.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say just from an image, but the space added between each class of math construct are user-settable parameters, I set them to zero here, although of course you could use other settings that shrink less aggressively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\def\zz{\frac{\partial J}{\partial W_S}=
 \sum_1^N \frac{\partial l}{\partial W}
+  \nu\sum_1^N \frac{\partial v}{\partial W}}

\[\zz\]

{\thinmuskip=0mu\medmuskip=0mu\thickmuskip=0mu
\[\zz\]}

\end{document}
```